# iOS Office365 send message 400 error

Tags: ios, message, office365

Using the [Office365 iOS library](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-365-SDK-for-iOS) I want to implement the send message functionality.

The code below, by running the sample code returns an error:

```
NSURLSessionDataTask* task = [[[client getMe] getOperations] sendMail:message :true :^(int returnValue, MSODataException *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

    [task resume]; }];

Error Domain=Error in the Request Code=400 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Error in the Request error 400.)" UserInfo=0x7cb3eee0 {error={
code = ErrorInvalidRequest;
message = "Cannot read the request body.";}}
```

Does anyone know a fix for this? It could be caused by a wrong sent payload message?

Comment: You found any success on this? Please tell me because I am stucking with the same issue.

Comment: @RaviGautam It seemed that the payload message sent was incorrect (I think some parameter was missing in the body - "attachment"). Instead of using the API I'm made the call using AFNetworking by creating the URL and the POST body by myself.

Answer (score 0):

That error does indicate a problem with the request payload. The common case is a missing Content-Type header. Can you capture a network trace and confirm? Also make sure you're using the latest release of that library.